# load more posts wordpress on click

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, infinite-scroll

i am working on a website with wordpress where i'm posting a post almost daily, the problem now is that the list of posts is getting a bit to long and I want to have the following: after every xx (number of) posts a button appears that gives the possibility to load the next xx (number of) posts.

I already tried to build in the infinite scroll javascript (both in code as well as the plugin itself) but I can't seem to make it work the way I want it.

I hope someone here can help me with the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this amazing tutorial that helped me with what I was searching for:
http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

problem solved! :)

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you, and thanks for sharing the source!

Comment: This answer has been flagged for removal because it is a link-only answer. Could you please expand this answer so it provides an answer to the question without requiring the reader to click to the linked webpage?