# Mixitup.js show more results

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using mixitup (http://mixitup.io) on a wordpress blog to allow a user to filter blog posts. The markup i'm using is as below:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li class="filter" data-filter=".white-paper">White Paper</li>
<li class="filter" data-filter=".webcast">Webcast</li>
<li class="filter" data-filter=".video">Video</li>
<li class="filter" data-filter="all">View All</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sort">
    <li class="white-paper">
        <h2>Post Title</h2>
        <a href=''>Read More </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously I have a longer lists of posts.

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement a 'load more posts' feature whilst using mixitup? Ideally, I'd like the page to display 6 posts at a time.

Any help on this topic would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could load new posts via ajax and append them to your list with the append-method.
https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/docs/#method-append

To load new posts via ajax follow
[load more posts wordpress on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167896/load-more-posts-wordpress-on-click)