# Wordpress Load More Posts onclick with ajax request jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've developed custom theme from scratch with _S starter theme. I'm having issue getting Wordpress next posts via ajax request on click on read more button. I've tried many articles specifically the following articles, but no luck.

**Reference Links:**

- [Load More Posts Ajax Button in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress)
- [Load Next WordPress Posts With AJAX](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/)
- [Load Old WordPress Posts on the Same Page with AJAX](http://www.codeinwp.com/blog/load-old-wordpress-posts-on-the-same-page-with-ajax/)

I've tried going with above custom loops and adding custom functions with jquery script but it don't work somehow.

Here is loop code example below:

**Loop in index.php**

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article class="post-item">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Sorry no posts are created yet.</h2>
    <p>Please create some posts to see it in action.</p>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<button class="load-more-btn">Load More</button>
```

I'm messing with this issue for over 4-5 days, so any one can help me out with this issue with working solution will be highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't mind using a plugin for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167896/load-more-posts-wordpress-on-click

Comment: Hello Clyff thanks for the reply. I've tried this plugin even tried to modify it to make it work, but by doing this my 'load more' button disappears as I've set 'posts_per_page' to 5 and I've more than 5 posts in my wp.

Comment: the plugin's name is PBD Ajax Load Posts

Comment: Also i don't want to go with Infinite Loop, cause its triggered automatically by going to bottom of the page. Instead i more like want triggering this on click.

Answer (score 5):

I maybe have a solution for your.

First be sure to have a script enqueue in your theme

```
wp_enqueue_script('your_js_hanlde', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your_js_hanlde.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
```

then localize add a function to add a js var in your dom

```
wp_localize_script('your_js_hanlde', 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
```

In your js, add an event on 'click' on your 'Load More' button

Pass an action name and the count of article you have in your dom, the response add the content before your button 'load more'

```
$("#load_more").click(function()
{
    $.post(ajaxurl,
    {
      'action': 'your_load_more',
      'count': $("article.post-item").length
    },
    function(response)
    {
      var posts = JSON.parse(response);

      for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ )
      {
        if( posts[i] == "0" )
          $("#load_more").fadeOut();
        else
          $("#load_more").before(posts[i]);
      }

    });
});
```

create a function in your functions.php

```
function your_load_more()
{
    $count = $_POST["count"];

    $cpt = 1;

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'post', // change the post type if you use a custom post type
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $articles = new WP_Query( $args );

    $ar_posts = array();

    if( $articles->have_posts() )
    {
        while( $articles->have_posts() )
        {
            $articles->the_post();

            $one_post = "";

            if( $cpt > $count && $cpt < $count+6 )
            {
                $one_post .= "<article id='" . get_the_id() . "' class='post-item'>";
                $one_post .= "<h3>" . get_the_title() . "</h3>";
                $one_post .= "</article>";

                $ar_posts[] = $one_post;

                if( $cpt == $articles->found_posts )
                    $ar_posts[] = "0";
            }
            $cpt++;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ar_posts);
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_load_more', 'your_load_more' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_load_more', 'your_load_more' );
```

It work for me.
I hope that help you.

Comment: Thanks yes it did worked for me. Although I need to load more features like  post_thumbnail, the_excerpt, the_permalink and the_post_metas etc.

Comment: You can easily do it, changing the loop content

Comment: Everything is done according to requirements thanks again, but there is still tiny problem, which is how i can disable or hide 'load more' button if there is no more posts left in loop.

Comment: I change my function. Pass posts in array and check if the current post in the loopt is the last. In that case, add a last item in the array with a custom value (ex: 0), then return the array encoding in json. In your js function, parse the array and check if the current item is equal to '0'. Hide the button. Work for me.

Comment: Thanks for updating the script, also again thanks alot for putting your efforts together to help me. Its really appreciable.let me try it with my theme.

Comment: I'm sorry this is still not working here. I'm getting somekind of white-space issue in JSON Parser. Here is the error below:

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: Is this something because of I'm on localhost? I'm using Xampp btw

Comment: Display the content of the array with console.log in your js before parsing. I need to know the content of the return.