# wp posts ajax load more

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I tried to load more posts using ajax. I see there is lot of plugins and solutions in online and stackoverflow. But none of work for me. Actually I want to do this without plugin. So I can use this in different page archive or different page template where I need this code.

Here is my code that I got from another question in stackoverflow. My score is lower, so I can't comment out there.

Here is my **index.php** code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="ajax-posts">
<?php 
    $postsPerPage = 3;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php
    endwhile; 
    echo '<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>';
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1;.
    var ppp = 3;

    $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){ 
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
        $.post(ajaxUrl, {
            action:"more_post_ajax",
            offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
            ppp: ppp
        }).success(function(posts){
            page++;
            $(".ajax-posts").append(posts); // CHANGE THIS!
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        });

   });

</script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is **functions.php** code

```
<?php 
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'offset' => $offset,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post();
       the_title();
    }
    exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
?>
```

I don't know why posts not load or not work load more link. I hope someone will be help.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588401/5545813

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress Load More Posts onclick with ajax request jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999193/wordpress-load-more-posts-onclick-with-ajax-request-jquery)

Comment: Hello @Nozifel I already tried your answer and unable to fixed my problem. Please check my code and let me know what is the wrong that I did !

Comment: Do you receive a response after your request ?
I suggest u first to change 'exit;' to 'die();'
i wait ur answer.

Comment: I used die(); but noting responded !

Comment: I tried on my config, remove 'header("Content-Type: text/html");', Then tell my if u get any js errors in ur console when u load the page.

After removed header and change $ to jQuery, it work for me.

Comment: Yes. jQuery work perfect. Thank you very much. Please help me little more...How can I hide the Load More link while no more posts?

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to return an array with ur post title. Then display them after the success. If the array length < ppp (there is no more post).

```
$array_return = array();
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post();
$content = "<h1>" . get_the_title() . "</h1>";
$content .= "<div>" . get_the_content() . "</div>";
$content .= "<div>" . get_field("your_field") . "</div>";
$array_return[] = $content;
}
echo json_encode( $array_return );
die();
```

In your js script,

```
var posts = JSON.parse(posts);
for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ )
    $(".ajax-posts").append(posts[i]);

if( posts.length < ur_ppp )
    $("#more_posts").fadeOut();
```

Something like that

Comment: There is not only title I want.. My posts have title, content & acf fields

Comment: I did a mistake.
I edit my code (error : json_encoRe => json_encode)

Comment: how I use `the_content();` and `the_field('field_name');` inside loop with array_return[] ?

Comment: really thanks for your code and efforts, but I think there is something wrong in your js script. for loop missed {} the bracket??  `for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ){ // Code Here ? }`

Comment: for( var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ){ $(".ajax-posts").append(posts[i]); } is the same thing. U don't need { if your use only one instruction.

Comment: OK. Actually I'm week in Ajax so I asked you. I added all of codes but its return only 0

Comment: will you give me the full code with your new code please?