# AJAX Load More For WordPress posts

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've had a. look on Stackoverflow for an answer and I've found some but unfortunately they don't work for my needs which is why I'm posting myself. If anyone could help me out that'd be great as I'm new to Ajax. I'm using the default WordPress posts post type within index.php default template.

Below is my HTML Code for outputting the posts:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 single_news_item">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Click here for our <?php the_title(); ?> post">
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
        <div class="bg_image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>');"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <p class="date"><?php $date = get_the_date('d / m / y'); echo $date; ?></p>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This is all I have. Essentially I need a "Load More" button or link to then load the next 3 posts and so on until there aren't anymore posts to load. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried so far to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: My question is how do I create a load more functionality using Ajax to load more WordPress posts.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Probably this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587210/load-more-posts-ajax-button-in-wordpress

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999193/wordpress-load-more-posts-onclick-with-ajax-request-jquery

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740471/wp-posts-ajax-load-more

Comment: I'll check these out now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an input field for saving the offset, once user click on button, here is the code.
NOTE: you should modify it according to you needs.

Add this in the end of loop where you get the data

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <input type="hidden" id="offset" value="10">
    <a class="btn btn-primary text-white load_more" id="load_using_ajax">Load More</a>
    <p id="test2"></p>
</div>
```

add this code in js, modify according to your needs

```
$(document).on('click','#load_using_ajax',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var button = $(this);
    var category = $('.active').data('category');
    var offset = parseInt($("#offset").val());

    $.ajax({
        url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            category: category,
            offset:offset,
            action: 'load_more_posts',
        },
        error : function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        success : function(result){
        if(result){
            $("#offset").val(offset+10);
            $('.append-ajax-release').append(result);
           
        }else{
            $("test2").append = 'No more Data Found';
        }
        }
        
    }); 
});
```

add this in you theme functions file need to modify according to your needs

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');

function load_more_posts()
{
    $offset = $_POST['offset'];
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $args = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' =>  10,
        'offset' => $offset,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query();
    $query->query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="row col-12 pressreleases-wrapper mt-5 mb-3 ml-0 ">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

}
```